# Theano vs. tensorflow backend in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, theano

I have a classifier model that I trained using 'theano' backend. The model works properly and I got the expected classification perforamance. The tensor size is `Nx3x28x112` However, I would like to use the same classifier in another file (main_file.py) which contains a GANs implementation (with'tensorflow' backend). Thereby, I want to use the same classificer in the main_file.py and to change the input size of the tensor in order to be `Nx28x112x3` (that is the proper input for the tensorflow backend). While the training procedure starts the performance is not close to the one I got with 'theano' and is close to random performance. My model looks like:

```
def createModel():

   model = Sequential()
   # The first two layers with 32 filters of window size 3x3
   model.add(Conv2D(28, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 112, 3))) 
   # or input_shape = (3, 28, 112) in case of theano backend
   model.add(Conv2D(28, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))

   return model
```

What should I do in order to make the model perform properly? Is there any fundamental difference when the backend is changing except the order of the input tensors?

Comment: are you talking about just at the start of training or on a trained model? Also, how do you specify the backend?

Comment: Keras by default has `"image_data_format": "channels_last"` and `data_format='channels_last'` is also a default parameter for say `Conv2d` and `Maxpool` layers. Make sure your format is correct for your backend.

Comment: I am defining the backend at the beginning of the file. My Generator and discriminator are defined for tensorflow and I want to do the same for the classifier model. However, I am not sure how to define properly the model for that case. The input data are reshaped in the channels_last order.

Comment: @Anakin what do you mean format?

Comment: I mean the data format. if your backend is set to TF and input data shape is fineas yours is, it should work. Everything else is by default set to TF format unless you changed them.

Comment: It works without error but the performance is very limited. When I shift to Theano I am getting the performance that I am expecting.

Comment: @ChrisTosh: If the Data and the Code is not confidential, please share those, so that we can try reproducing the issue at our end. Thanks!